# Accessing data from constructor inside static method

Tags: javascript, oop

Hello i play around with web components https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements

```js
function createComponent({
  template = null,
  name = null,
  data = null,
  methods = null
}) {
  let classes = {};
  classes[name] = class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.vDOM = {
         element: "<button>test</button>"
      };
      this.attr = Object.values(this.attributes);
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = this.vDOM.element;
    }

    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ["color"];
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldval, newvaL) {
      console.log("changed happend");
    }
  };
  window.customElements.define(name, classes[name]);
}

createComponent({name: "testing-it"});

let bttn = document.getElementById("bttn");
bttn.addEventListener("click", change);

function change() {
   let el = document.querySelector("testing-it");
   el.setAttribute("color", "blue");
}
```

```html
<testing-it color="red"></testing-it>

<button id="bttn">change attr</button>
```

As you can see here in this example, whenever you click "change attr" the observer gets triggerd. My problem is now that i want it to be more dynamic.

It requires an array and with `Object.values(this.attributes)` i am able to collect all attributes, but i am not able to use it in the static method like `return this.attr`

Is there an way to observer multiple attributes dynamic without to specifi it on the begin?

Comment: Doesn't seem like you can specify to observe generic attributes. However, you can add your own mutation observer: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/565#issuecomment-345556883

Comment: @NickParsons thank you. looks interessting i will test it out

Comment: @NickParsons thank you, my one-way-bindings seems to work